# How to give parameter to a docker image in docker file so that it still works in Apple M1 Machine

Tags: java, macos, docker, dockerfile, apple-m1

I used to be able to download openjdk:8-jdk-slim as below

```
docker run -it --name my-container openjdk:8-jdk-slim
```

After moving to Apple M1 MacBook Pro, I have to use this parameter `--platform linux/amd64` as stated in https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/apple-silicon/

```
docker run -it --platform linux/amd64 --name my-container openjdk:8-jdk-slim
```

But for a Dockerfile I have

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-slim

// Other codes
```

How can I add the needed parameter to it, so that the Dockerfile still work on my Apple M1 MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `--platform` option to a `FROM` statement as well:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 openjdk:8-jdk-slim
...
```

It's mentioned in the [Dockefile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from):

> The optional `--platform` flag can be used to specify the platform of the image in case `FROM` references a multi-platform image. For example, `linux/amd64`, `linux/arm64`, or `windows/amd64`. By default, the target platform of the build request is used. Global build arguments can be used in the value of this flag, for example automatic platform ARGs allow you to force a stage to native build platform (`--platform=$BUILDPLATFORM`), and use it to cross-compile to the target platform inside the stage.

Comment: I'm trying to add this platform flag to my backend dockerfile and and getting an error, can't even add the flag. If you happen to know how to fix that, [here's the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70754255/how-can-i-correctly-specify-the-platform-for-my-dockerfile)