# How can I correctly specify the platform for my dockerfile?

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to add the --platform=linux/amd64 flag to my dockerfile's FROM statement. I need to do this because I'm working on an m1 laptop and the default architecture (linux/arm64/v8) is not compatible with our prod machine. The whole line should be:

`FROM --platform=linux/amd64 openjdk:11-jre-slim`

This worked fine for my frontend repo (with node as the base image). However, in the backend repo, I'm getting this error:

`<name chain> expected, got '-'`

So it's like, not letting me add the flag at all for some reason.

IntelliJ IDEA, Java

Full backend dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 openjdk:11-jre-slim
COPY config/dev.yml /opt/dropwizard/
COPY build/libs/smerge-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar /opt/dropwizard/
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /opt/dropwizard
CMD ["java", "-jar", "smerge-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar", "server", "dev.yml"]
```

The [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) on the --platform flag for dockerfiles says that:

*The optional --platform flag can be used to specify the platform of the image in case FROM references a multi-platform image. For example, linux/amd64, linux/arm64, or windows/amd64. By default, the target platform of the build request is used.*

Comment: Could you please add your backend repo docker file

Comment: Sure thing -- done

Comment: What is your host platform (windows/linux/etc)? Which Docker do you use (ce/desktop and version)? Since the problem only occurs in a certain project, have you tried to move the necessary files away into a new directory and perform the build there?

Comment: I can perform a build, I'm asking about the dockerfile specifically.

Comment: My image built from M1 Mac won't run on Cloud Run, figured it was a platform issue. I passed the platform using docker buildx:
`docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 --tag REPO:TAG .`

If your docker version doesn't come with buildx you have to install it - https://docs.docker.com/build/buildx/install/

Answer (score 3):

On Mac, I add this line to the *.zprofile* and that takes care of everything at once. Adding it to the .zprofile, for me, ensures the DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM is present in the environ on accessing the terminal.

> export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64

Answer (score 2):

Also, I use this cmd to build docker image from the apple silicon macbook.

```
docker build --platform=linux/amd64 -t mydockerimage .
```

No need for buildx